# Getting "Unidentified Index" while getting selected dropdown value in php form

Tags: php

My html code looks like below.

```
<select name="datasetownercluster">
<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>                                                                                      


</select>
```

and my php code looks like below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$datasetownercluster = $_POST['datasetownercluster'];

}?>
```

But it gives me an error like "Notice: Undefined index: datasetownercluster in C:\xampp\htdocs\Access\insert\insert.php on this line"

Comment: `<option value='a'></option>`

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: `$datasetownercluster = $_POST['datasetownercluster'] ?? null;`

Comment: error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Access\insert\insert.php "

Comment: Then you're using an older version of PHP; I can almost guarantee that the answer will be in the duplicate this has been flagged as though.

Comment: I'm using "Current PHP version: 5.6.30"

Comment: As I said, an older version, the *current* version is 7.2

Comment: I changed to latest version so right now there is no error but while connecting to MYSQL database it creates problem as newer version is only compatible with MariaDB